# How to write a WOL app for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, wake-on-lan

Wake on LAN so cool, just want to write a iPhone app to WOL my PC, but have no idea to code, any one can point me the way?

Comment: Even if you knew how to program it would probably take you a couple of weeks to learn the intricacies of how the networking portion work.

Answer (score 3):

If you've no experience of programming, then this is a very large first step. (More of a sheer vertical incline really.)

As such, you might want to take a step back and have a look a some basic (or indeed BASIC) programming tutorials. (Google is your friend.)

Alternatively, Apple has good online documentation regarding Objective C and the Cocoa (the language and framework that iPhone applications are written in.) A good place to start for this would be [Apple's Introduction to The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html).

Comment: You'll need a program to create a socket that sends a very specifically formatted packet from the iPhone. You also need to configure your router to forward port 9 to the local network's broadcast IP address (255.255.255.255).

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to send a magic packed as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Magic_packet), to do that you'll need basic programming knowledge and some knowledge on socket programming, here is a [good book](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) on the subject. There are numerous examples of [that](http://gsd.di.uminho.pt/jpo/software/wakeonlan/mini-howto/wol-mini-howto-3.html).

But in the end perhaps I could persuade you to purchase one of [several iPhone applications](http://ax.search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?entity=software&media=all&page=1&restrict=true&startIndex=0&term=wol) that do exactly that, or grab the [free one](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/remoteboot-lite/id310369182?mt=8)?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an understanding of bsd sockets as well as the user interface kit framework to put the necessary controls on the screen.

Or of course download an existing free app like this one which does it already, automatically detects your mac address, and also tells you whether your machines are on or off:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wake/id396566137?mt=8

All the best for your projects.